# Set Navigation Controller Parameter from TabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've been struggling with this for quite some time and I can't seem to find anything here that directly relates. My **goal** is to pass a core data object from the login screen to my first view. My first view is linked to a navigation controller and the navigation controller is the first tab on a tab bar controller.

Through prepareForSegue, I can pass the object no problem to the tab bar controller but that's when things get confusing, how do I pass the object stored in the tab bar controller to the navigation controller?

Any help would be much much appreciated!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TabBar` is holding the array of `ViewController` and since your `ViewController` is inside `NavigationController` you can use this code to pass the object you want to the `ViewController` inside the `NavigationController`from `prepareForSegue`

```
UITabBarController *tabBarCtr = segue.destinationViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabBarCtr viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
YourViewControllerClass *viewControl = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
viewControl.myObject = self.myObject
```

Comment: Incredible. Just incredible. I just tested it and it works, besides that, things make so much more sense now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```c
UITabBarController *tabBarCtr = segue.destinationViewController;
SearchItemTypeViewController *viewControl = [[tabBarCtr viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```